# How to remove record with sum and condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a **table** like this

| NUMBER_ID | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -5000 |
| 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 1000 |
| 2 | -1000 |
| 3 | 3000 |
| 4 | -3000 |
| 4 | 2000 |

what I want is

| NUMBER_ID | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3000 |
| 4 | -1000 |

I want do sum TOTAL from the same NUMBER_ID and when result of sum is equal to 0, then record of the NUMBER_ID and TOTAL is gone. Else of that the record still show..

Can you help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by `NUMBER_ID` and then assert that the sum of the total is not zero:

```sql
SELECT NUMBER_ID, SUM(TOTAL)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NUMBER_ID
HAVING SUM(TOTAL) <> 0;
```